# gui using tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

**main.py**

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import *


import main_support


def popup1(event, *args, **kwargs):
        Popupmenu1 = tk.Menu(main_support.root, tearoff=0)
        Popupmenu1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        Popupmenu1.configure(activeborderwidth="1")
        Popupmenu1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        Popupmenu1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        Popupmenu1.configure(borderwidth="1")
        Popupmenu1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        Popupmenu1.configure(font="-family {Segoe UI} -size 9")
        Popupmenu1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        Popupmenu1.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)


class Header:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.methodSelectionValue = []
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.style.map('.',background=[('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])

        top.geometry("600x450+664+264")
        top.minsize(120, 1)
        top.maxsize(1924, 1061)
        top.resizable(1,  1)
        top.title("Toplevel 0")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#f0f0f0f0f0f0")
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.top = top
        self.combobox = tk.StringVar()

        self.Label1 = tk.Label(self.top)
        self.Label1.place(relx=-0.033, rely=0.0, height=41, width=634)
        self.Label1.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label1.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label1.configure(background="#b90746")
        self.Label1.configure(compound='center')
        self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label1.configure(font="-family {Calisto MT} -size 16 -weight bold -slant italic")
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#ffffff")
        self.Label1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''Calculator''')

        self.TFrame1 = ttk.Frame(self.top)
        self.TFrame1.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.12, relheight=0.856, relwidth=0.958)

        self.TFrame1.configure(relief='groove')
        self.TFrame1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.TFrame1.configure(relief="groove")

        self.Labelframe1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.TFrame1)
        self.Labelframe1.place(relx=0.47, rely=0.026, relheight=0.948, relwidth=0.504)
        self.Labelframe1.configure(relief='groove')
        self.Labelframe1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Labelframe1.configure(text='''Main Window''')
        self.Labelframe1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Labelframe1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Labelframe1.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.Label2 = tk.Label(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Label2.place(relx=0.038, rely=0.11, height=31, width=90, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Label2.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label2.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label2.configure(anchor='w')
        self.Label2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label2.configure(compound='left')
        self.Label2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label2.configure(text='''Class Selection''')

        self.TCombobox1 = ttk.Combobox(self.Labelframe1, values=['Basic', 'Advance'])
        self.TCombobox1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.setMethodValue)
        self.TCombobox1.place(relx=0.421, rely=0.121, relheight=0.058, relwidth=0.531, bordermode='ignore')
        self.TCombobox1.configure(textvariable=self.combobox)
        self.TCombobox1.configure(takefocus="")

        self.Label3 = tk.Label(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Label3.place(relx=0.038, rely=0.274, height=21, width=111, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Label3.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label3.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label3.configure(anchor='w')
        self.Label3.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label3.configure(compound='left')
        self.Label3.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label3.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label3.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label3.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label3.configure(text='''Method Selection''')

        self.TCombobox2 = ttk.Combobox(self.Labelframe1, values=self.methodSelectionValue)
        self.TCombobox2.place(relx=0.414, rely=0.274, relheight=0.058, relwidth=0.528, bordermode='ignore')
        self.TCombobox2.configure(textvariable=self.combobox)
        self.TCombobox2.configure(takefocus="")

        self.TEntry1 = ttk.Entry(self.Labelframe1)
        self.TEntry1.place(relx=0.138, rely=0.493, relheight=0.112, relwidth=0.262, bordermode='ignore')
        self.TEntry1.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TEntry1.configure(cursor="ibeam")

        self.Label4 = tk.Label(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Label4.place(relx=0.207, rely=0.411, height=21, width=74, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Label4.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label4.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label4.configure(anchor='w')
        self.Label4.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label4.configure(compound='left')
        self.Label4.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label4.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label4.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label4.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label4.configure(text='''Input 1''')

        self.TEntry2 = ttk.Entry(self.Labelframe1)
        self.TEntry2.place(relx=0.621, rely=0.493, relheight=0.112, relwidth=0.262, bordermode='ignore')
        self.TEntry2.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TEntry2.configure(cursor="ibeam")

        self.Label5 = tk.Label(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Label5.place(relx=0.655, rely=0.411, height=21, width=44, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Label5.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label5.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label5.configure(anchor='w')
        self.Label5.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label5.configure(compound='left')
        self.Label5.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label5.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label5.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label5.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label5.configure(text='''Input 2''')

        self.Button1 = tk.Button(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Button1.place(relx=0.397, rely=0.685, height=34, width=57, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(compound='left')
        self.Button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button1.configure(text='''Run''')

        self.TFrame2 = ttk.Frame(self.TFrame1)
        self.TFrame2.place(relx=0.017, rely=0.026, relheight=0.948, relwidth=0.426)
        self.TFrame2.configure(relief='groove')
        self.TFrame2.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.TFrame2.configure(relief="groove")

    def setMethodValue(self, event):
        selectedValue = self.TCombobox1.get()
        if selectedValue == "Basic":
            self.TCombobox2["values"] = ["Add", "Sub"]
        elif selectedValue == "Advance":
            self.TCombobox2["values"] = ["Multiply", "Division", "Modulus"]
        self.TCombobox2.current()


def start_up():
    main_support.mains()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_support.mains()
```

**main_support.py**

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

import main


def mains(*args):
    '''Main entry point for the application.'''
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' , root.destroy)
    # Creates a toplevel widget.
    global _top1, _w1
    _top1 = root
    _w1 = main.Header(_top1)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main.start_up()
```

Created two dropdowns one is for class selection and other is for method selection of that particular class. class name: basic, advance, method selection: basic: add,sub, advance:multiply, division and modulus. currently struck at issue where i select class as basic, it shows basic in method selection dropdown also which is not inteded. thereafter if i select class as basic and in method i select add, class which has to be basic is also getting changed to add. help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used same tkinter variable `self.combobox` for both `Combobox` widgets.

Remove the line:

```py
self.TCombobox2.configure(textvariable=self.combobox)
```

Or use another tkinter variable for `self.TCombobox2`.

Comment: thanks. can you please post that whole main.py along with these changes.

Comment: @Arun I think it is not necessary to post the whole `main.py` if only one line is need to be removed.

Comment: can you help me add a image in TfFame2 as well.

Comment: @Arun `self.background = tk.PhotoImage(file="/path/to/image.png")`, `tk.Label(self.TFrame2, image=self.background).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')`.

Comment: in image=self.background throws error. AttributeError: 'Header' object has no attribute 'background'??

Comment: @Arun Did you add the line `self.background = tk.PhotoImage(file="/path/to/image.png")` as well?

Comment: It worked. was a spelling mistake while typing.